# Server is hammered by frequent chat requests

Tags: linux, apache

I've got a closed system with chat in it. The chat updates every 10 seconds, for 30 active in house users. After every couple of hours, suddenly the chat's server (based on Linux, using Apache2) just takes 30 seconds to respond and needs restarting. My hypothesis is that the server sees many connections from the same IP, and just blocks us. Is there a setting I can change to make the server not delay frequent connections).

Also, I cannot find anything online about in house servers, only multiple connections from multiple users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of polling data, an approach of using a `socket` does not have this problem, and is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it shouldn't be a problem with 30+ connections.
Try to track down these ones:

```
netstat -atun | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sed -e '/^$/d' |sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

But at all I think it's a type of apache issue. 
Just search for the error.log (/var/log/apache2/*.error.log) and try to track down the problem. Maybe the parent process is randomly restarting?